# Virtual Host config not working in Centos 8 Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, http, http-status-code-500, centos8

I have never faced this issue before , but on this fresh install of CentOS 8 and apache 2.4 , I am trying to add new virtual host in vhost.conf  file in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/, as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName db.example.com
ServerAlias db.example.com
DocumentRoot /usr/share/mysite

<Directory /usr/share/mysite>
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I tested config
#apachectl configtest

Syntax OK

But still when this  is present in conf.d , server throws HTTP 500 error. When I remove this file and restart server , welcome page is shown.

I am totally lost here , please help

Comment: What does the error_log.txt say? It is located in /var/log/httpd/

Comment: No log for this in error_log

Comment: What about the access log then? Also try to put a file hello.txt in /usr/share/mysite/ and then request http://db.example.com/hello.txt - If that still fails look for the text hello.txt in the access and error logs. Also: Are you sure that apache has read access to /usr/share/mysite?
Also: This may be a selinux issue. Try to temporary disable selinux and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add virtual host on /sites-available, create a site.conf inside then do a2ensite site.conf

follow this tutorial for exact steps

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7

Comment: That seams to me extremely complicated way to configure virtual host. I do one enterprise site per instance , not a regular hosting, had been conveniently doing  one virtual host conf file inside conf.d folder and all used to work seamlessly. Not sure what's wrong in that. That was easy and straight forward method.  Why  can't I do it like earlier days?

Comment: Just follow steps, its no rocket science, thats how you learn it forever

Comment: Understand, but we have made  an application to deploy & configure our applications, using virtual hosts in conf.d . It has been working well since last many years,  we need to do major changes there that will cost us  too

Answer (score 0):

This was sad but I had to move back to CentOS 7 due to to time constraint. Used same configurations there and it worked with a charm.

In centos 8, it was reading the configurations, as I had spell mistake in path in the  .conf file for which apache threw the error (file not found) . But moment it was corrected it again threw error 500.

Then I had to revert to centos 7 and all worked , I saved lot of time.